# Converting pixel color (bytes to bits & bits to bytes)

Tags: java

I wanted to manipulate the image by playing with the pixel bits. So, I wanted to covert the pixels I grabbed from PixelGrabber. The argb value were in bytes. Now I want to convert array of bytes into bits and manipulate it. And then convert back to bytes array.

For Example: 
-1057365 into 11101111 11011101 10101011 11111111 and 
11101111 11011101 10101011 11111111 into -1057365

Anyone know there's any efficient way to converting between them? Or java has method implemented for it and I don't know.

Thx for helping.

Comment: Why not just stick to bitmasking and bitshifting so you can interact with them as small ints? Much more convenient than bits. And if you really wanted to you could deal with 1 and 0 for a single bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html).

```
byte[] argb = ...
BitSet bits = BitSet.valueOf(argb);
bits.set(0); // sets the 0th bit to true
bits.clear(0); // sets the 0th bit to false

byte[] newArgb = bits.toByteArray();
```

/edit
To convert a `byte[]` to an `int`:

```
int i = 0;
for(byte b : newArgb) { // you could also omit this loop
    i <<= 8;            // and do this all on one line
    i |= (b & 0xFF);    // but it can get kind of messy.
}
```

or

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
bb.put(newArgb);
int i = bb.getInt();
```

Comment: can it converting 11101111 11011101 10101011 11111111 into -1057365?

Comment: You can convert a `byte[]` to an `int` by using shifts. See my edit.

Comment: sry.. what the mean by bits.set(0); // sets the 0th bit to true
bits.clear(0); // sets the 0th bit to false

Comment: @user1621008 An `int` has 32 bits. `bits.set(0)` would set the first bit to `true`, or 1. `bits.clear(0)` would set the first bit to `false`, or 0.

Comment: I got some idea with it. Thank you! but I think I need new java version to use BitSet class right?

Comment: @user1621008 `BitSet` has been around since JDK 1.0

Answer (score 4):

I Assume that the value that you have is a raw 4-byte int representation of the ARGB code.
Each of the channels is 1 byte wide ranging from 0 to 254, together they make up the whole range of 0-255^4 (minus 1).

The best way you can acquire the different channel values is by combination of masking and shifting the argb value into different fields.

```
int alpha = (pixel >> 24) & 0xff;
int red   = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
int green = (pixel >>  8) & 0xff;
int blue  = (pixel      ) & 0xff;
```

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/PixelGrabber.html)

Comment: Reverse: `(alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue`

Comment: Yes. Im using this way to get my bits. But I having the problem converting bits to bytes. what i mean is 11101111 11011101 10101011 11111111 into -1057365

Comment: In what type of variable do you store the values?